# Give a formal grammar G that satisfies L(G) = L

Tags: computation-theory, formal-languages

I have the following question given to me in a past exam paper. I understand the solution (kind of?) but wondering if anyone knows how the solution is actually generated (or a different easier solution).

Give a formal grammer G that satisfies L(G) = L ...

```
L := {w member of {a,b}* | n does not exist in N : w = (ab)^n}
```

the answer is:

```
G : ({A,B,S},{a,b},P,S) with
P := { 
       S-> a | empty | bA | aB | aaA
       A-> aA| bA | empty
       B-> aB | bB | a | aaA | bbA  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `n does not exist in N` what is `N`

Comment: N are the natural numbers including zero.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but this might help others nonetheless.

The language you give is the set of all words which can't be written as a (possibly empty) concatenation of the string `ab`; that is, all words except the ones in `(ab)*`.

That the language requested is the complement of a simpler language is the avenue we will take to find a grammar. First, we can write a DFA for the language `(ab)*`:

```
Q   s   Q'
q0  a   q1
q0  b   q2
q1  a   q2
q1  b   q0
q2  a   q2
q2  b   q2
```

The initial state, `q0`, is the only accepting state. `q2` is a dead state.

To get a DFA for the language we want, we can simply *swap the accepting and non-accepting states* of this DFA. That is, to accept the language that contains strings that can't be written as `(ab)^n` for any natural number `n`, we simply make `q1` and `q2` accepting instead of `q0`.

To get a grammar from a DFA is very easy. Nonterminal symbols correspond to DFA states. Transitions in the DFA become productions in the grammar. If you have a transition from state `q` to `q'` on symbol `s` in your DFA, and nonterminal symbols `A` and `B` correspond to `q` and `q'`, you get a production `A := sB` in your grammar. If `q` is an accepting state in your DFA and `A` corresponds to `q`, then you also have a production `A := e` where `e` is the empty string. If you don't want empty productions (except possibly `S := e` as required) then you can also handle accepting states by duplicating productions. This is one way to do the construction; there are others that are just as good.

For our case:

```
S ~ q0
A ~ q1
B ~ q2

S := aA      f(q0, a) = q1
S := bB      f(q0, b) = q2
A := aB      f(q1, a) = q2
A := bA      f(q1, b) = q0
B := aB      f(q2, a) = q2
B := bB      f(q2, b) = q2
A := e       q1 is accepting
B := e       q2 is accepting
```

We can now write EBNF by combining lines:

```
S := aA | bB
A := aB | bA | e
B := aB | bB | e
```